# Proof of coset/subgroup property

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I am given a proof of the following property:

> The only left coset of $H$ which is a subgroup of $G$ is $H$ itself.

The brief proof is based on the following properties:

> 1)  $xH = H \iff x\in h$
> 2) $xH \cap yH =xH$ or $\varnothing$

I understand the proofs of the two above properties. Now the given proof of the coset/subgroup property goes as follows:

> Since $e\in H$, $e\not \in gH$ for all $g \in G$ and $g\not \in H$ by properties **1** and **2**.
> $\therefore$ no coset of $H$ besides H contains $e$, the unique identity in $G$.
> $\therefore H $ is the only coset of $H$ which is a subgroup of $G$.

I don't understand what is going on in the first line, it seems that they're trying to find cosets in which the identity from $H$ will not be present. The second line makes sense, it seems relatively obvious to me, though I assume it is based off of the first line... As for the third line it seems like they are 'magically' jumping to it, though I assume that may be because of my lack of understanding of the first line.

So, what is happening in this proof?

Comment: It’s not “the identity from $H$”, it’s the identity of the group. Recall that a subgroup of $G$ **must** contain the identity element of $G$. Now, which cosets of $H$ in $G$ contain the identity? $H$ does; but in fact, it’s the only coset that does, because distinct cosets are disjoint. So no other coset contains $e$, so no other coset can possibly be a subgroup of $G$. So the only coset that could possibly be a subgroup is $H$ itself, which in fact is a subgroup.

Comment: Each element of the group $G$ is an element of exactly one left coset of $H$. A subgroup of $G$ must contain the identity element of $G$, so there is just one left coset of $H$ that could possibly be a subgroup, the left coset containing the identity of $G$. But that coset is $H$ which really is a subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They're trying to find cosets in which *the identity from $H$* will not be present.

As a subgroup of $G$, "the identity of $H$" *is* the identity of $G$, namely $e$. Remember, every subgroup is a group in its own right, but also contains the identity of the larger group (as its own identity element).

> The second line is based (sic)off of the first line.

Indeed, it is. I'll explain both lines, starting from the first.

Note that $e \in H$, so by property $1$ we have $eH = H$. Next, if $L$ is any other coset, then by property $2$, we have $L \cap H = \emptyset$. In other words, $e \notin L$. This is what the second line is saying in words : " no coset of $H$ besides $H$ contains $e$, the unique identity of $G$".

> "It seems line they are magically jumping to it".

As I mentioned earlier, every subgroup of $G$ contains the identity element of $G$, so every coset *other than $H$* doesn't have the identity so cannot be a subgroup!

This leaves $H$ as the only option, but we know that it is a subgroup, so the conclusion is that it is the only coset that is a subgroup as well.